# cron expression to run the job at specified time?

Tags: java, spring, java-ee-6, quartz-scheduler, cronexpression

I am using Spring Quartz and i have a  job which runs `every 10 mins`. It is working fine without any issues using `cron` expression.

But now i have below requirement.

It has to run every 10 mins, but it should not run in the time mentioned below.

```
Sat 5pm to Sun 9am
Sun 5pm to Mon 9am
```

How can i write the `cron` expression to satisfy above condition using single cron expression? Job has to run every 10 mins but it should not run in the time mentioned above.

Thanks!

Comment: I think this is where the power of the cron expression is not enough by itself. I would be hesitant to recommend handling the situation in the jobs though (I mean the job would start, but first check if it is in a blackout period, and would not do anything if it is in the mentioned periods)

Comment: so, i need to handle it through logic right?

Comment: I think yes. But I'm not 100% sure, just say 99%... Quartz is powerful and widely used, and this seems to be a sensible requirement, so I'd think there is a way... Just that I don't know about one.

Comment: okay..Thanks ppeterka..any other alternative that u can suggest?

Comment: You would need more than one cron expression to achieve this.  Each  cron expression could trigger the same job.

Comment: so, i can have list of cron expressions and i need to loop through each one right? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You probably need 4 quartz cron expressions:

```
0 0/10 * ? * TUE-FRI
0 0/10 0-16 ? * SAT
0 0/10 9-16 ? * SUN
0 0/10 9-23 ? * MON
```

You can use [online cron expression checker](http://www.cronmaker.com/) to verify quartz-cron expressions.

Comment: You can combine 2nd and 3rd expressions into one like `0 0/10 0-16 ? * SUN,SAT`

Comment: No, you can't. It gives 0-16 on Sunday but 9-16 is required.

Comment: Ha ha... Sorry, I wasn't wearing my glasses, I swear I saw a 0 instead of 9 on the Sunday schedule.